# Sencha modern application viewcontroller not binding being called?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs

First of all to stress it: I'm using sencha **modern**.
Well consider the following view:

```
Ext.define('myApplication.view.main.OrderView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'ordercontainer',
    controller: 'order',

    requires: [
        'Ext.MessageBox',
        'Ext.layout.Fit'
    ],

    viewModel: 'main',

    defaults: {
        tab: {
            iconAlign: 'top'
        },
        flex: 1
    },

    layout: 'vbox',

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'test, to be updated',
            height: 30,
            flex: 0,
            listeners: {
                click: 'onClick'
            }
        },
    ]
});
```

With the corresponding controller:

```
Ext.define('myApplication.view.main.OrderController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',

    alias: 'controller.order',

    onClick: function () {
        debugger;
        alert('onClick');
    }
});
```

now I can see the button when the page is loaded. I expect the onClick function to be called (as per [guide](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/guides/application_architecture/view_controllers.html#application_architecture-_-view_controllers_-_listeners)). However it is not. I don't see any alert, nor will (when development console is open in chrome) the debugger halt on the onClick function.

If I change the button to use a `handle` and use code-behind it works. Yet the view controller doesn't work. This shouldn't fail right? Or did I once again fall into the trap of using a guide for classic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because in **Modern** the [components](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.Button.html) doesn't have event `click` but [`tap`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.Button.html#event-tap)

So change your code like this:

```
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'test, to be updated',
        height: 30,
        flex: 0,
        listeners: {
            tap: 'onClick'
        }
    },
]
```